# How to import CSV containing boolean values into Neo4j

Tags: csv, import, neo4j, boolean

I am currently trying to import CSV data using Cypher into Neo4j.

Unfortunately, I cannot find a way to convert a certain column (true/false) from String to Boolean. When using e.g. a Case-When construct, the boolean value is used to decide whether a node should be created or not.

Hence my questions: what am I doing wrong?

Here's the data:

```
"UUID", "Name", "IsSelectable"
"1", "Abc", 1
"2", "Def", 0
```

And the cypher statement:

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM 'file:///<path>' AS row
CREATE (:Category {UUID: row.UUID, Name: row.Name, IsSelectable: ???})
```

Many thanks in advance,
Oliver

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use the `CASE WHEN THEN ELSE END` expression.

See the cypher reference card: http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/cypher-refcard

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM 'file:///<path>' AS row
CREATE (:Category {UUID: row.UUID, Name: row.Name, 
       IsSelectable: (case row.IsSelectable when 1 then true else false end)})
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I already tried that approach.  
  
It only works if I change it to:  
    `LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM 'file:///<path>' AS row  
    CREATE (:Category {UUID: row.UUID, Name: row.Name, IsSelectable: (case toInt(row.IsSelectable) when 1 then true else false end)})`  
And then it only inserts the row where IsSelectable is 1. The row with 0 is skipped.

Comment: My mistake, your suggested solution works. Many thanks!

Answer (score 6):

You can use `toBoolean` to cast the 1/0 to true/false

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM 'file:///<path>' AS row
CREATE (:Category {
    UUID: row.UUID, 
    Name: row.Name, 
    IsSelectable: toBoolean(row.IsSelectable)
})
```

Answer (score 1):

```
(case row.IsSelectable when 1 then true else false end)
```

Results false for all values. Should be:

```
(case row.IsSelectable when '1' then true else false end)
```

since LOAD CSV only reads Strings.

Comment: Many thanks @Lee46, I had the string issue, it works on 3.4.4. toBollean() doesn't works on 3.4.4 BTW